# Wrong image on facebook catalog

Tags: facebook, csv, catalog

I have developed a daily csv file with php and mysql technology. Facebook uses this csv to show all our products on our facebook store.

The problem is that facebook displays a wrong image for some products.  I have checked my csv and the image is right.

After that, I accessed to facebook catalog administration over a wrong image, then I saw that the product is showing the right image on the administration page.

Example:

Wrong image: https://www.facebook.com/products/image/?item_id=2344243688984642&display=multi&version=1&image_id=2169702346485626&image_width=186&image_height=186&display_option=background_padding&logging_boundary=item_preview

The right image that appears on 'edit product': https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCLCxZ9xrRUhd9m&url=https%3A%2F%2Fshop.atosa.es%2Fimg%2Fp%2F1%2F0%2F1%2F1%2F1011.jpg&_nc_hash=AQDWNd_Ct7njTn3V

It seems the wrong image is hosted by facebook and the right image by our server

I think that FB has a cache or something similar that do not update the image.

Any idea to update that wrong images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe once before when you've been creating your catalog you still served a wrong image to FB. When FB fetches you feed now it sees the same URL and doesn't update the image because of that.

The solution would be to add any arbitrary parameter at the end of you image link like.

`https://youserver/image.jpg?id=1`

It should still return your image, but be a new link so that FB could recognize smth has change. It helped in many cases I had with wrong images in catalogs.

The ultimate solution would be to change the product's ID in the feed which will lead to FB creating an absolutely new product in the catalog. Mind, that it will discard product stats and you'll have to send that new ID in pixel or you mobile app.

Try the link solution first. You can also duplicate the product just adding a test one to the feed and check if a new fake test product looks correctly.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have added this random variable like you said substr(md5(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20)),-10); and it works facebook updates the image qith the right image.

Comment: My csv runs daily  and sometimes the image change but it has the same id https://shop.atosa.es/img/p/1/1.jpg?fb=62a7ee357e" Now with this arbitrary parameter faebook updates the image.

Comment: Yep, Charlyu, that's exactly how FB sees that smth has changed. Unfortunately FB doesn't mention it explicitly in the docs. I'm happy it worked for you!